# Web service calls 32 bit dll function

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, dll

I have created web service that uses some external dll. Evrything works fine when I run web service on IIS Express from VS IDE. Web service call dll functions without problems. But when I publish this web service to local computer IIS and call method that exposes dll function I got error:

> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program
>   with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

According information I found on internet it might bee 64/32 bit compatibility issue. My dll is compiled like 32 bit app.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728339/iis-7-5-fixing-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-pr)? Might have some useful info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `IIS` go to the `Application Pools`.

Select the Application Pool of your web service then click on "`Advanced Settings`".

Look for the option "`Enable 32-Bit Applications`" and set it to `true`.

Then restart IIS and try again.

I had a similar problem and I solved in this way